# Remove and keep entire row in a file if a column is repeated

Tags: python, bash, awk

I'm trying to do something like this

Input file

```
123  09
123  10
355  07
765  01
765  03
765  05
```

Output file 1

```
123 09
355 07
765 01
```

Output file 2

```
123 10
765 03
765 05
```

I mean. I want two eliminate (entire row) if there are repeated values in column 1, but actually I want to put this values in another file.

I know that I can obtain output 1 with

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file
```

But is it possible to obtain output 2???

I'm open to python scripts.

Comment: Convert your input file to dictionary, and for each key in dictionary and check if values for that key > 1 then add to other file.

Answer (score 3):

One way with awk

```
awk '{print >("file"(!a[$1]++?1:2))}' file
```

or

```
awk '{print >("file"(a[$1]++?2:1))}' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton I find it easier to understand with the negative as i use them more. I will add the positive one as well though and then people can choose whichever they prefer :) Atleast i remembered the brackets surrounding the filename this time!

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, with with regards to selecting specific lines, i use it a lot to find unique lines. so it just sort of became natural to use the negative and then sometimes to even invert that back to positive. Obviously I understand this is not great practice though!

Comment: this one is very clean

Answer (score 1):

This an easy and readable python script that will do the job.
If you have any question please comment.

```
# open all the files
with open('output_1.txt','w') as out_1:
    with open('output_2.txt', 'w') as out_2:
        with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
            #make list that stores intermediate results
            tmp = []
            #iterate over each row of the input file
            for row in f:
                #extract the data contained in the row
                col_1, col_2 = row.split('  ') #split the line at double space

                #check if you have met col_1 before
                #if not, write the row in output_1
                if col_1 not in tmp:
                    tmp.append(col_1)
                    out_1.write(row)
                #otherwise write the row in output_2
                else:
                    out_2.write(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

For both the 1st and the 2nd outputs you can use this awk command:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++{print > "output1"; next} {print > "output2"}' file

cat output1
123  09
355  07
765  01

cat output2
123  10
765  03
765  05
```

Comment: Thank you, but your output is "123 10, 355 07, 765 05" and I'm looking for "123 10, 765 03, 765 05"

Comment: `756` in your output2 is not even there in input file

Comment: Edited 756 problem (now 765)

Comment: I misunderstood question earlier. It is updated, please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Python:

```
seen = set()
with open('data.txt') as fin, open('f1.txt', 'w') as fout1, open('f2.txt', 'w') as fout2:
    for line in fin:
        col = line.split()[0]
        if col in seen:
            fout2.write(line)
        else:
            seen.add(col)
            fout1.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
awk '{if($1 in a){ print > "Output2" }else{ print > "Output1"} a[$1]=true}' input
```

you get in Output1 file

```
123  09
355  07
765  01
```

you get in Output2 file

```
123  10
765  03
765  05
```

if, you want get only output2 then remove `!` in your code

```
awk 'a[$1]++' input
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this job directly in `bash`.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# file names
file=input.in
dupes=dupes.out
uniques=uniques.out

# an (associative) array to track seen keys
declare -a keys

# extracts a key from an input line via shell word splitting
get_key() {
  key=$1
}

# Removes old output files
[ -e "$dupes" ] && rm "$dupes"
[ -e "$uniques" ] && rm "$uniques"

# process the input line by line
while read line; do
  get_key $line
  if [ -n "${keys[$key]}" ]; then
    # a duplicate
    echo "$line" >> "$dupes"
  else
    # not a duplicate
    keys[$key]=1
    echo "$line" >> "$uniques"
  fi  
done < "$file"
```

It could be shortened in a variety of ways; I wrote for clarity and a bit for flexibility at the expense of brevity.

It's anyway important to understand that `bash` is a pretty powerful programming environment in its own right.  One of the things that slows many shell scripts is use of a lot of external commands.  Using external commands is not *inherently* bad, and sometimes it's the best or only way to get the job done, but where that's not the case you should give serious consideration to avoiding them.

Comment: You can do it directly in assembly code too but why would you? The above will fail cryptically given various input file contents. It's hard to write text processing loops robustly in shell since that's not what shell is for. It will also, obviously, be immensely inefficient compared to an awk solution.

Comment: `One of the things that slows many shell scripts is use of a lot of external commands`.Really ? `while read` makes a system call for every byte. It is possibly the slowest way to process a file.@EdMorton At least in assembly it would be quick.

Comment: @User112638726, Yes, really.  Launching a child process is fairly expensive.  As for bash's `read` builtin, you're full of it, as you can verify for yourself via `strace`.  Bash reads blockwise into a buffer; in this particular case, my bash is using a 128-byte buffer for the job.

Comment: @EdMorton, if this job must be performed in the context of a larger shell script, then `bash`'s *somewhat* lesser efficiency for it will still beat the rather large cost of launching a child `awk` process, unless the input is far, far larger than the example.  And yes, you do have to consider whether the contents of the input will be safe with respect to this particular implementation, but that's not inherently a disqualifier.  At some level, you always have to consider whether *any* implementation is correct for the predictable input.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm full of it ? If you think a while read loop will outperform awk for text processing then you are delusional.

Comment: @User112638726, a having a shell that's already running use a `read` loop for simple processing of a few lines of text absolutely will outperform *starting a new `awk` process*, and in it, performing equivalent text processing.  For such a small job, `awk`'s specialization for such work doesn't come close to compensating for the cost of starting it up.  It would be different if the alternatives were "start a shell to do it" and "start `awk` to do it", but that's not the scenario I described.

Comment: @JohnBollinger At the level where shell outperforms awk, the performance difference is so negligible that it honestly makes no difference at all and even then it only outperforms on the most basic of tasks. Whereas with large file the difference is huge in favor of awk. I've tested this before and it stopped being more efficient after like 40 lines. If you are having performance issues processing 40 line files using awk, then you are certainly still going to have them using a read loop. There is no situation i can think of where using a read loop is advisable over awk for processing text.

Comment: @JohnBollinger see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765 from the person who knows shell better than anyone else I've come across and discovered the shellshock bug.